# How can I fire an event on the server without a page refresh in WebForms

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

As it says in the title I want to have a button/link that when clicked it adds a number to a table in a database but stays on the same page without refreshing the page. It would also be nice if it said "Thanks" after clicking.

I was thinking that I could use some sort of JavaScript thing to do it.

I am using C# and aspx.

Comment: Don't put the whole question in the title.

Comment: Are you using MVC/WebForms/etc? There will be different server-side code for each of these.

Comment: ajax will perform an asynchronous call to your server which you can wait for a callback to even add a new link or change a link on your page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with an AJAX postback.

With jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Depending on your server-side framework, your back-end method may have to be setup slightly differently. [Here's one example using webforms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET).

You can update the `success` or `complete` callback method of the `ajax` call to update the DOM or `alert('Thanks')` for completed behavior, too.

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to do this or do I need to learn how to do ajax fully. Thanks

Comment: a regular postback won't suffice?

Comment: jQuery makes ajax usage very simple; you'll have to learn the javascript syntax for it and create a method in your C# that it can talk to.

Comment: without refreshing was included in the constraints of the question

Comment: @Morpheus "stays on the same page without refreshing the page"

Comment: @braza this *is* the easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go for jQuery ajax. 
Check out this [article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) it gives really good insights on using jquery ajax in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Put a button and label inside an UpdatePanel with `ChildrenAsTriggers=true`. Add a button and in its `OnClick` method, simply insert the row into the table and set the label's text appropriately.